# WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: plugins, database, mysql, errors, wpdb

after wordpress update to 3.5+ i get error in this plugin.

I do not understand how to fix it. If anyone can help me with these problem or give me an example of how to fix it

here is the full code of the plugin: http://pastebin.com/pVUXjWat

the errors i get:

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_jsrm_menus' at line 1 for query SHOW TABLES LIKE wp_jsrm_menus made by activate_plugin, do_action('activate_simple-retail-menus/simple-retail-menus.php'), call_user_func_array, jsrm_activate_loop, jsrm_activate
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_jsrm_items' at line 1 for query SHOW TABLES LIKE wp_jsrm_items made by activate_plugin, do_action('activate_simple-retail-menus/simple-retail-menus.php'), call_user_func_array, jsrm_activate_loop, jsrm_activate
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_jsrm_menus' at line 1 for query SHOW TABLES LIKE wp_jsrm_menus made by do_action('activate_simple-retail-menus/simple-retail-menus.php'), call_user_func_array, jsrm_activate_loop, jsrm_activate
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_jsrm_items' at line 1 for query SHOW TABLES LIKE wp_jsrm_items made by do_action('activate_simple-retail-menus/simple-retail-menus.php'), call_user_func_array, jsrm_activate_loop, jsrm_activate
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_jsrm_menus' at line 1 for query SHOW TABLES LIKE wp_jsrm_menus made by do_action('activate_simple-retail-menus/simple-retail-menus.php'), call_user_func_array, jsrm_activate_loop, jsrm_activate
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_jsrm_items' at line 1 for query SHOW TABLES LIKE wp_jsrm_items made by do_action('activate_simple-retail-menus/simple-retail-menus.php'), call_user_func_array, jsrm_activate_loop, jsrm_activate
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_jsrm_menus' at line 1 for query SHOW TABLES LIKE wp_jsrm_menus made by activate_plugin, do_action('activate_simple-retail-menus/simple-retail-menus.php'), call_user_func_array, jsrm_activate_loop, jsrm_activate
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_jsrm_items' at line 1 for query SHOW TABLES LIKE wp_jsrm_items made by activate_plugin, do_action('activate_simple-retail-menus/simple-retail-menus.php'), call_user_func_array, jsrm_activate_loop, jsrm_activate
```

all the sql queries here

```
function jsrm_activate() {
        add_option('jsrm_val_cols', '2');

        global $wpdb;
        $jsrm_menu_table = $wpdb->prefix . "jsrm_menus";
        $jsrm_item_table = $wpdb->prefix . "jsrm_items";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

        if (!empty ($wpdb->charset))
                $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $wpdb->charset";
        if (!empty ($wpdb->collate))
                $charset_collate .= " COLLATE $wpdb->collate";

        if ($wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE $jsrm_menu_table") != $jsrm_menu_table){

                $sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $jsrm_menu_table (
                                id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                menuorder mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
                                name tinytext NOT NULL,
                                description text,
                                label tinytext NOT NULL,
                                itemheader tinytext NOT NULL,
                                valueheader tinytext NOT NULL,";

                for ($v=2;$v<=JSRM_VALUE_COLS;$v++){
                        $sql1 .= "valueheader" . $v . " tinytext NOT NULL,";
                };             
                $sql1 .= "UNIQUE KEY id (id)
                                ) $charset_collate;";

                dbDelta($sql1);
        }

        if ($wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE $jsrm_item_table") != $jsrm_item_table){

                        $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $jsrm_item_table (
                                id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                menu mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
                                itemorder mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
                                item tinytext NOT NULL,
                                description text,
                                image tinytext,
                                linked tinyint(1),
                                linkurl tinytext,
                                itemhidden tinyint(1),
                                value tinytext,";

                        for ($v=2;$v<=JSRM_VALUE_COLS;$v++){
                                $sql2 .= "value" . $v . " tinytext,";
                        };     
                        $sql2 .= "UNIQUE KEY id (id)
                                ) $charset_collate;";
                dbDelta($sql2);
        }

}


// CHECK DATABASE TABLES ON INIT AND UPDATE IF NECESSARY

function jsrm_check_database_version(){
        $dbversion = get_option( 'jsrm_db_version', '1' );
        if ($dbversion != JSRM_DB_VERSION){
                jsrm_activate_loop();
        }
}
add_action('init', 'jsrm_check_database_version');
```

Comment: Quote your table name in the `SHOW TABLES` `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to fix this. You can either remove the if-condition containing `SHOW TABLES LIKE` (remove lines: 117, 135 and 137, 157). That should work as the dbDelta function checks itself if the tables are already presend. 
Or you could just add some single quotes to the table names in the lines 117 and 137:

```
"SHOW TABLES LIKE '$jsrm_menu_table'"
```